# MS Project Successor Tasks based on Predecessor Task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, tasks, microsoft-project

I am trying to create a high-level plan that contains tasks that must happen before Sprint starts.  For example, Task 1 must end 3 weeks prior to the start of Task 2. Task 2 has a fixed date.  However, should Task 2's date change (mgmt. decision), Task 1 must move and still end 3 weeks prior to the start of Task 2.  Any suggestions on how to show this is MS Project 2010?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? Can you share examples or screenshots?

Comment: All I've tried is to enter '1FS+3w' for the Task 2 dependency.    But the problem is that Task 2 in  this example is the real driver of the plan, meaning that if I add that for the dependency Task 2 will adjust to changes with Task 1.  If I didn't have so many tasks then I could  manually just try to remember that I need to calculate and change Task 1's date by the appropriate # of days.  But since I have ~100 tasks it's not very easy to keep track of since each task may have a different differential (i.e. some tasks need to start 2d prior, or 2w prior or whatever).  Make sense?